# How can I stop classic-asp page from submitting form when the user presses enter in IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp-classic

I've got an ASP-classic page coming along, and there's a login dialog (made using jquery).  The user clicks login, and the dialog pops up and asks for a password (no username needed.  Small group).  If they enter their password and physically click login, everything works fine.

However, if they hit enter, somehow, the "form" submits, even though there is no form, and the url updates to `http://xxx.xxxx.xxxx.asp?password=whatever` and my login code doesn't execute (because the login button wasn't clicked).  Weirdly enough, I just found that if the user goes to `http://xxx.xxxx.xxxx.asp?` instead of `http://xxx.xxxx.xxxx.asp` (note the question mark at the end), hitting enter inside the dialog doesn't do anything.

Any idea why this happens and how I can stop it?

EDIT:  Here's the HTML for the dialog:

```
<div id="login-form" title="Log in">
    <p class="validateTips">Please enter your password.</p>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
</div>
```

and here's the jquery for it:

```
$( "#login-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 350,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Log In": function() {
          var bValid = true;
          allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );


          if ( password.val() == 'skeet' ) {    
                        setCookie("loggedIn","true",1);
                        alert("Logged in");
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );        
                        location.reload();                      
          }
                    else
                    {
                        alert("Invalid Password");
                    }
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
      }
    });
```

Comment: since it is for a small group you could force it to use compatibility mode?

Comment: run your login code on form submit instead of button click

Comment: @woony how can I do that?  I've never done anything with compatibility mode before

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ the problem is that I don't even have a form.  It's just a `<div>` called login-form. There's no form to it.

Comment: you can use this meta tag
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" >
I don't know how to properly format this here :)

Comment: Nope, still submits when I hit enter, but I appreciate the attempt

Comment: This may seem weird, but I've seen some other places that said ie8 is finicky with jquery's dialogs if they have invalid html... so please try taking the self close out of the input tag just <input stuff> instead of <input stuff />  since input's are void tags

Comment: This [does not happen](http://jsfiddle.net/BsPwE/) in IE10 or Chrome, guess it's IE8 (or less) only issue. How many users have it? being small group can't you make them upgrade to IE10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a `<input type="submit">`, use:

`<input type="button" onclick="document.forms[0].submit()">`

...assuming there is only one form on your page.

Comment: That's the thing: I'm not using either of them.  When I build the dialog in my jQuery code, I just create buttons and then user .click() on them.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure it is a bad practice to nest your inputs outside of a form. Your browser might add it for you internally.
Could you try to add a form around your inputs and this?

```
<form onsubmit="return false">
  <div id="login-form" title="Log in">
  ...
  </div>
</form>
```

Your page should not submit when hitting ENTER.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/qXrjD/

The problem is you will not be able to submit your form after that, but you might not face the issue.

Comment: Hmm, this didn't do it.  See, I don't think it's an actual _form_ that's submitting.  I think ASP is seeing my password field and automatically submitting _that_ when I hit enter.  No button click seems to be happening or anything.  It just takes whatever I had entered in the password field and throws it in the url

Answer (score 0):

I've kludgily handled this with an onkeydown in the past, I can't find my old code now but something like this:

```
<input type="password" onkeydown="EnterHandler();" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
```

then this JS

```
function EnterHandler(){
    if (window.event.keyCode == 13){
        window.event.returnValue =false;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm.. that still didn't stop it.  I think somehow the ASP is executing before any javascript gets the chance.